# unordered_map not iterating all keys

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I have the following code to iterate over all the keys in an unordered_map, while iterating I pass the map to some other function. Due to some reason the iterator is not able to iterate over all keys. I am not able to figure out why and how to fix this. If I pass the map as value instead of reference then it works as expected, but I want to pass by reference to save the copy.

Code:

```
void DFS(char curr, unordered_map<char, unordered_set<char>>& G) {
    cout << "Traversing: " << curr << endl;
    for(const char& ch: G[curr]) {
        DFS(ch, G);
    }
}

int main() {
    unordered_map<char, unordered_set<char>> G;

    G['c'].emplace('b');
    G['b'].emplace('a');

    for(auto it : G) {
        cout << "Starting with: " << it.first << endl;
        DFS(it.first, G);
    }
}
```

The output I get is:

```
Starting with: b
Traversing: b
Traversing: a
```

Note that it is not traversing key `c`.

**UPDATE:**
Changing the DFS function to make the map const like below is also not helping:

```
void DFS(const char curr, const unordered_map<char, unordered_set<char>>& G) {
    cout << "Traversing: " << curr << endl;
    for(auto ch: G.at(curr)) {
        DFS(ch, G);
    }
}
```

And it is throwing an exception as well:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  _Map_base::at
```

Comment: Is `DFS` expected to modify `G` or not? If not, make it `const` and fix the errors that appear. If so, can you explain why you expect it to traverse `c`?

Comment: Changing to constant is also not helping rather causing an exception. Please see the update section. I am expecting `c` to be traversed from `main` function as it is also a key.

Comment: Okay, so you don't expect `DFS` to modify `G`. Yet it is, causing an exception. Do you know how to debug an exception on your platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial attempt was modifying the map, adding an entry for `a`. The second attempt threw the exception failing to find the entry for `a`.

It sounds like you want to end your search when the value isn't in the map.

```
void DFS(const char curr, const unordered_map<char, unordered_set<char>>& G) {
    cout << "Traversing: " << curr << endl;
    auto it = G.find(curr);
    if (it != G.end()) {
        for(auto ch: it->second) {
            DFS(ch, G);
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can initialise the `a` entry in the map, and any of these three options will work (although the non-`const` version is the least safe, in that has undefined behaviour when you fail to find)

```
int main() {
    std::unordered_map<char, std::unordered_set<char>> G;

    G['c'].emplace('b');
    G['b'].emplace('a');
    G['a'];

    for(auto it : G) {
        cout << "Starting with: " << it.first << endl;
        DFS(it.first, G);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It is because you're changing the map you're iterating over.  You have to be cautions when doing that, as a if a rehashing occurs during the [emplace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/emplace) all iterators are invalidated.

Comment: I am not able to understand where I am changing the map. Can you please tell me the line?

Comment: @saha `G[curr]` will insert an entry if the value of `curr` is not already a key in the map. That's how you can have `G['c'].emplace('b');`